# How can I reach my ASP.NET project with my smartphone?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET project which developed in visual studio 2010 on my computer.
I can open its pages using address like : localhost:52413/Default.aspx .

I want to reach that page from my smartphone which is connected in same wireless network. How can i do that. First of all i tried 192.168.2.2:52413/default.aspx

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Visual Studio built-in development server, then you are not going to be able to open the website on another computer (or smartphone). This web server is bound to localhost. But you have three options to test your website on your smartphone:

1. Use IIS Express

   - [Install IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038)
   - [Change project settings to use IIS Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/03/14/enabling-iis-express-support-in-vs-2010-sp1.aspx) instead of the built-in web server
   - [Configure IIS Express to listen to remote requests](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx).
2. Use IIS

   - [Install IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/)
   - [Change project settings to use IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis/) (instructions for Visual Studio 2008, mostly the same in Visual Studio 2010)
3. Transfer your files to a web host where you have a domain name and hosting contract

For 1. and 2. you probably also need to configure your local machine's firewall to allow incoming traffic.

Comment: i have iis express but i couldnt understand what do you mean with "change project settings to use IIS express"

Comment: @user1137664 Right-click the project and choose ["Use IIS Express..."](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-63-56-metablogapi/8032.UseIISxContextMenu_5F00_thumb_5F00_2E7E9809.png)

Comment: @user1137664 See this post from Scott Guthrie for more details on [how to use IIS Express in Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite easily using Fiddler.
[www.fiddler2.com](http://www.fiddler2.com)

First download and install Fiddler.
Start the program and select "**Tools**" -> "*Fiddler Options*" from the menu.
In the options dialog select the "**Connections**" tab and check "**Allow remote computers to connect**".
A 'restart required' dialog may appear.

Now select "**Rules**" -> "**Customize Rules**" from the menu.
This opens a text file called "**CustomRules**". At the end of the "**OnBeforeRequest**" method (around line 188 or so) add the following:

```
if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "192.168.2.2:8888")
            oSession.host = "localhost:2000";
```

Save the file. Close it. Restart Fiddler.

Start your web application (I usually configure the web site with a static port) like normal and verify that it's viewable on the computer through localhost:2000 (or whatever port number you have decided to use. It must match what you entered in "**CustomRules**", though).

Now you should be able to browse the web application from any device on your lan provided firewall and such let you by pointing a browser to http://192.168.2.2:8888

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the firewall on your computer is blocking connections to port 52413. Try turning off the Windows Firewall to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

local development server can be use only from local machine, publish to your app to  or you can install [UtilDev](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx) Web server (former Cassini)